# How to update the version of gems of a locally cloned heroku ruby on rails repository using bundle?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I wanted to know how to update the gems on a heroku ruby on rails repository that cloned in to a local machine.Can we use bundle to update the gems like ***puma***.I've used ***bundle install*** after cloning the repository and pointing to the repository using terminal. Is that ***bundle update*** will solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the version of gems in **`Gemfile`**

Just change or add the versions to gem

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'puma', '3.6.0'
```

And bundle it

```
bundle install
```

Comment: It works like a charm!